# how to make multiple list boxes scroll with arrow keys

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I want to be able to scroll 4 list boxes at the same time with arrow keys just like they do individually when the curser is clicked on each individual list box? Is there an event or command that can control this so like binding it to any button?

Comment: I forgot to mention that all the list boxes have an equal number of items in them.

Comment: Have you tried calling `.yview_scroll(<y_steps>, "units")` on each listbox? `y_steps` should be an integer.

Comment: Is it possible to get the position of the item that is show at the top of any listbox. I already thought of a way to fix my issue, but I just need to be able to get he new position and set all the other ones equal to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind on the virtual event `<<ListboxSelect>>` to synchronize the view of the 4 list boxes as `Up`, `Down`, `Control-Home` and `Control-End` keys will change the selection of the list box as well as the viewing region.

However `PgUp` and `PgDn` keys will not update the selection of the list box, so we need to call the callback of the above virtual event to synchronize the view region of those list boxes.

Below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def on_selection_changed(event):
    pos = event.widget.yview()[0] # get current view region of selected listbox
    selected = event.widget.curselection()
    # sync other listboxes
    for lb in listboxes:
        if lb is not event.widget:
            # update view region
            lb.yview_moveto(pos)
            if selected:
                # update selection
                lb.selection_clear(0, 'end')
                lb.selection_set(selected)

def on_scroll(event):
    # use after() to make sure the scrolling has been done by default handler
    # before synchronize those listboxes
    event.widget.after(0, on_selection_changed, event)

root = tk.Tk()

listboxes = []
for i in range(4):
    lb = tk.Listbox(root, width=20, exportselection=0, activestyle='none')
    lb.pack(side='left')
    lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection_changed)
    lb.bind('<Prior>', on_scroll) # PgUp
    lb.bind('<Next>', on_scroll)  # PgDn
    lb.bind('<MouseWheel>', on_scroll)
    listboxes.append(lb)
    # insert dummy items
    for j in range(30):
        lb.insert('end', f'Item #{i+1}.{j+1:02}')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've been looking at this for a while trying to understand it, but I'm not sure how I to add the 4 list boxes I have into this since the way you made yours, they are names the same I think.

Comment: @neo_codex You just need to understand what events need to be bound on those list boxes and what need to be done inside those callbacks.  Then you can apply the logic to your own code.